# How to get the fitted parameters using sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score?

Tags: scikit-learn

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) provides this example:

```
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
>>> scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(
...    clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
...
>>> scores                                              
array([ 0.96...,  1.  ...,  0.96...,  0.96...,  1.        ])
```

What good are the scores by themselves? Is there a way to get the parameters for the best performing model?

Comment: `opt_params = clf.fit(X_grid, Y_grid).best_estimator_`

Comment: What are `X_grid` and `Y_grid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for another method if you want to do model selection: `grid_search.GridSearchCV`, see the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)

More specifically, `cross_validation.cross_val_score` only compute a cross-validated score, which means you do not change the parameters of the model, you only vary the data used for training and testing the model.

What `grid_search.GridSearchCV` is doing is computing a cross-validated score for each point in the grid, i.e. each set of parameters. This allows you to select the best set of parameters, i.e. the one with the highest score.

In AGS answer, clf would thus be:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1), tuned_parameters, cv=5,
                   scoring='%s_weighted' % score)
```

I think [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_digits.html) is pretty similar to what you are trying to do.